# Data copy Cython

Tags: python, c, cython

I have a .pyx file where a large File is being scanned in chunks. Ex- 100 MB data is scanned into 10 parts of 10 MB each

While doing this I have these two values
    - the offset of the File 
    - and the length of the data to scan

I want to make a copy of each portion of data into a random Python empty list.

I was doing this by:

```
class abc
..
cdef object buff

def do_scan(self,...)
   ...
   self.buff = []
   ...
   buff.append(PyString_FromStringAndSize(<char *>offset,length))
   ...

   fh = open ("tmpf.bin","wb")
   cPickle.dump(buff,fh)
   fh.close()
   ...

...
Error:
NameError: PyString_FromStringAndSize is not defined
```

This is not giving my the desired output.

Can anyone help how can I copy a  data into Python object ???

Comment: I've voted to close as lacking a [mcve]. 1) It isn't complete. 2) What is the desired output and what is it giving instead?

Answer (score 0):

Your immediate problem is clearer in light of the error message: you haven't told Cython about `PyString_FromStringAndSize`. The easiest way to do this is to `cimport` it from the default CPython wrappers supplied by Cython

```
# at the top of your pyx file
from cpython.string cimport PyString_FromStringAndSize
```